# Postgresql STRICT function with null record input argument

Tags: sql, postgresql, null

In PostgreSQL 9.4 I have a function that accepts a record (table entry) as an input argument.  The function is `STRICT`, so I would expect that, if the input is a null record (e.g `(NULL,NULL,NULL)`), the function would not be called and I'd get `NULL` output.  This is desired behavior since my function is computationally expensive.

But PostgreSQL seems to think that a null record really isn't null when deciding whether or not to call the function, and my expensive function gets called anyway, resulting in garbage output.  Note that the function is written in `C`, and I didn't bother handling `NULL` inputs, since I used the `STRICT` keyword.

Here's a small example to illustrate the problem:

```
create table test_table as
  select null::int as a, null::int as b;

create function rec_func(test_table) returns text as
$$
  select 'Function got called'::text;
$$
language sql strict;

select t, t is null as is_null, coalesce(t,(1,2)::test_table), rec_func(t)
from test_table t;
```

The output  from the select query:

```
t           is_null  coalesce    rec_func
test_table  boolean  test_table  text
----------  -------  ----------  -------------------
(,)         t        (,)         Function got called
```

Accord to the `IS NULL` operator, the input record ( , ) is indeed `NULL`, but `coalesce()` returns ( , ) as if it's not `null`, and `rec_func()` gets called as if it's `not null`.

It looks like PostgreSQL's internal check for `NULL` input that is used by `coalesce()` and any `STRICT` function is different from the `IS NULL` operator.  Any ideas what's going on? To address my specific problem, what can I do to make sure my function does not get called when a record input is all `NULL`s?

One last note - I understand that there's some ambiguity about whether or not a record is null if the entries are mixed - some `NULL`, some not.  But fortunately I don't have to handle this case, since all the columns in the table I'm using as input are `NOT NULL`. So any time my function is called, the record contains either all nulls or all non-nulls.

Comment: That is interesting case. It seems that record with `NULL` attributes isn't considered as `NULL`. The only thing that comes to mind is to create some intermediate function in plpgsql that checks record for `NULL`s and then passes it to original function (to `rec_func()` in your example).

Answer (score 0):

When you call a `STRICT` function with a `record` parameter the check is made at the level of the row: is a row passed as a parameter or `NULL`? The contents of the row are not checked. The solution is that you should check the value of any field in the record at the start of the function and `RETURN NULL` if `NULL`, process the remainder of the function otherwise.

Comment: So the parameter check is different from `IS NULL`?  Since `rec IS NULL` would evaluate to `TRUE` in the case of a record with all `NULL` entries...?

Answer (score 0):

As a turn around use [`nullif`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to make an explict `null` when passing the record:

```
select rec_func(nullif(test_table, (null,null)::test_table))
from test_table
```

Comment: As I stated at the beginning of the question, the actual function I'm using is in C, not sql...